# Scanning for files and directories recursively in Python

Tags: python

I want to scan a directory fully for its children (either dir or file)...

I know `os.walk()` solution but I want to know how this is achieved using regular loops, is it possible?

I mean if :

```
for item in directory :
    if os.path.isdir(item)

   ...
```

But the above code just goes deep into directory as many levels of for-loop as you have manually written which seems imperfect and odd.

I ask this question to know if is there any trick (other than built-in functions) to go recursive into the deepest file of a directory...

Comment: You'd need to recursively search the directories see dfs

Comment: See [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html). They have examples there. Also, a search for **os.walk example** will give you a bunch of code to get started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, you can write a recursive function to examine all the files:

```
def rec_walk(dir):
    contents = os.listdir(dir) # read the contents of dir
    for item in contents:      # loop over those contents
        if os.path.isdir(item):
            rec_walk(item)     # recurse on subdirectories
        else:
            print(item)        # do something else with non-directory items
```

If you're gathering information from the non-directory files (rather than just printing their names, like I did above) you probably will need to do something with the return values from the recursive calls. The details will depend on what exactly you're doing.

Comment: I just see self-calling of the function does the job here, thanks

Comment: How to `return` all these entries for further processing later on? It seems more difficult than expected to do this (I either end up with `None` as return, or with the first file from the first dir returned). I tried to use `os.scandir` since it is now [recommended](https://peps.python.org/pep-0471/).